# fish `while read` blocks until stdin is finished while sh/bash computes immediately

Tags: bash, shell, stream, pipe, fish

Take the following sh/bash script:

```bash
{
    echo abc
    sleep 2
    echo def
} | while read f; do
    echo $f "has been piped"
done
```

The block represents a command that slowly produces output on separate lines. For each line a computation is launched as soon as it reaches stdin of `while`.

If we translate this to fish:

```
begin
    echo abc
    sleep 2
    echo def
end | while read -l f
    echo $f "has been piped"
end
```

the behaviour unexpectedly changes: for two seconds nothing happens and then we get both lines of output at once. The entire while block does not start computing until the stream finishes sending data.

Why does the behaviour in fish differ and how do you make it match sh/bash?

Comment: FWIW, The [Elvish shell](https://elv.sh) is multithreaded and exhibits the desired behavior. Here is the Elvish equivalent of your Bash example: `{ echo abc; sleep 2; echo def } | each {|l| echo $l "has been piped" }`.

Comment: @KurtisRader Thank you! The Elvish Shell looks promising and I will try it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does the behaviour in fish differ and how do you make it match sh/bash?

This is a limitation of fish - it can only run one piece of script at the same time.

Bash/sh in contrast uses subshells - i.e. it forks off another process and keeps them running there. This comes with some major downsides - notably, variables can't be shared across subshells and they are weirdly implicit in some cases (and different across posixy shells - is the last process in a pipeline run in a separate subshell or not?).

The long-term plan is for fish to gain multi-threaded execution.

Your workaround is to start a separate fish process manually:

```
fish -c 'echo abc; sleep 2; echo def' | while read -l f
    echo $f has been piped
end
```

Comment: I see. I knew it was missing some process substitution features but I didn't know it all ran sequentially. Thanks!

Comment: Could you link me to some more information/discussions on the planned features?